# Clear cache for specific domain name in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-cache

I want to clear the cache for a specific domain name in Chrome. Is there an extension or other method that I can use to do this?

Comment: The problem with this is that it is not as simple to clear the cache as you would think. When a browser caches files, it does so based on its URL. The complication is that many sites *share* common files like Google API scripts, Gravatar icons, etc. How would you go about clearing the cache for only a specific site? Should the common files it loads be deleted as well (and thus partially clearing the cache for other sites)? Or should they be left intact? (probably the most “correct” solution).

Comment: Honestly, none of these answers really "answer" the question for me. These are developer answers. The root question is how a regular person would do this. It would be unreasonable to ask a non-developer to do these things.

Comment: It's times like these when I switch back to Firefox for a day.

Comment: No one has really answered this question about how to clear cache for a specific domain

Comment: Since F12 developer tools is built into Chrome, using them is open to everyone, not just "Developers" for clearing specific items.

Answer (score 435, accepted):

UPDATE: As of Chrome version 110.0.5481.104, you can perform the following steps:

<kbd>F12</kbd> > `Chrome Developer Tools` > `Application` tab > `Storage` in left tree > Select the data items to clear, then click `Clear site data`.

---

This may be a quicker/simpler way:

- Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Chrome Developer Tools (will pop up from bottom)
- Click settings "gear" icon in top-right corner
- Under **Network** (previously **General**) check **Disable cache**
- Reload page and re-enable caching by un-checking this box

Comment: Thanks, this actually works unlike the other answers which confuse cache and cookies ;-)

Comment: But does it actually *clear* the cache for the page or just load it without using the cache? That is, if you open the cache directory, are any files related to that page gone after you reload?

Comment: That's a pretty manual way of doing it and can get annoying if you have to do it multiple times. Fortunately there's an easier and faster way: http://superuser.com/a/598260/83619

Comment: Currently Chrome Developer Tools seems to disable cache only while DevTools is open without actually clearing it.

Comment: `alt ⌥` + `cmd ⌘` + `i` on **Mac** to open Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: There should be an extension for this.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  A hotel in Bangkok cached a redirect to their login page on one of my most-used URLs.  It has been driving me CRAZY!

Comment: Just to add, under the chrome://settings/cookies/ area, there is data stored as "local storage" which may come under a general definition of "cache" even though it is technically a cookie.  Long story short: clearing the cache didn't work for me but clearing the "local storage" cookie did.

Comment: IMHO this does not answer "clear the cache for a specific domain name in Chrome" - it clears cache only for a single page, not the whole domain.

Comment: I tried this multiple times to no avail. I'm still seeing the old Twitch design, whereas I see their new one if I load the site in an incognito window. I'm not sure what is causing this, maybe some incorrect settings for app caching on their side. I really wonder however, why there doesn't seem to be a not-too-complicated way in Chrome to clear the entire cache for a certain domain or reload a page fully like in Firefox.

Comment: Either of the options are not working for me :(. It is an SSL website. I don't want to clear the cache of the entire browser as suggested in another post [here](https://superuser.com/a/722548/374397).

Comment: My bad. Your solution is correct. Actually I was expecting my auto-fill user id and password for a website to get cleared/erased after clearing cache of the browser through your suggested methods. Now I realized that auto-fill user id and passwords are not stored in the cache of the browser. I already upvoted your post for a great answer. :)

Comment: Note: it's December 23, 2017 and just the first method worked for me. Thanks! :)

Comment: Clear Cache & Cookies for specific website in Chrome.  Follow this menu tree.  Newer versions of Chrome have this tree.  I'm on version 67.0.x Windows 10.  
Settings | Advanced | "Privacy and security" | "Content settings" | Cookies | "See All cookies and site data" | search by site

See also:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/clear-cache-cookies-specific-website

Comment: I'm running Chromium 75. No General, and no Disable Cache. There's a Disable Cache checkbox on Network tab though.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but Tom Auger's answer below did: https://superuser.com/a/598260/74576

Comment: This does not work for me today in Windows Chrome

Comment: `ctrl` + `shift` + `i` in Chrome 91 on Linux to open Developer Tools

Comment: NOT SOLVED THE ISSUE

Comment: Step 1 should be "Goto the website you want to clear cache for",,, don't just start by saying open dev tools. Cause them I'm gona open it on Stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 130):

After opening up the developer tools (usually by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>) Click + Hold on the "Reload Page" button. From the popup list, choose "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".

Not sure this clears the cache for the entire domain. But probably satisfies 90% of the use cases of people that visit this SE question.

**Note:** In some cases this will NOT open the popup list. This is because the page isn't cached at that time, so the menu is not invoked.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on mac.

Comment: Try having the Developer Toolbar open first - hit F12 (or CMD+SHIFT+C for Console). I haven't tested on a Mac.

Comment: thanks @Hashbrown for the edit. I should have amended my answer.

Comment: no worries. this solution is just faster than the selected answer, and less drastic than just disabling the cache altogether. I feel this needs to be up the top, and the only way it'll get upvotes is if people test it and it works for them

Comment: [Indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633425/chrome-browser-reload-options-new-feature#comment18973528_12648186), no cigar on a Mac for me neither. Bummer.

Comment: How is this different from a shift-reload? Also, it only seems to clear the cache for the current page, not all pages on a domain as the OP asked.

Comment: Use right-click on GNU/Linux to open the pop-up menu instead of a long click.

Comment: In my case it was extension DataSaver that hold old inpractical data. Turning it on and off solved the problem.

Comment: Yes! this cleared a cached `.htaccess` redirect  The other answer (`Clear site data`) didn't work for my case.

Comment: Ditto. This cleared a stubborn cached `.htaccess` redirect for me too. Many thanks. It's probably worth pointing out that the "Reload Page" button isn't in the Developer Tools window, but is the familiar button adjacent to the address bar on a standard browser tab.

Comment: I can't find a reload page button anywhere. Can you add or link to a screenshot?

Comment: This clears the whole cache, not just a specific domain.

Comment: Doesn't work at all for me on Windows Chrome.  My Mac can access the domain just fine, PC cannot.  Most frustrating.

Comment: step 1. While on the website you want to clear. 2. do this stuff^....
if i start following your instructions now. i'll clear stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 57):

Here's how to delete Chrome's cookies selectively by domain or subdomain:

- go to `chrome://settings/siteData` (earlier versions: `chrome://settings/content/cookies`)
- type the domain name in the search box
- click delete

More details here:

> http://oxid-blog.euroblaze.de/miscellaneous/delete-google-chrome-cookies-selectively-by-domain/

This can't however select cookies by web folders, e.g. `www.domain.com/folder1`.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.

Comment: The question was about clearing the _cache_, but you answered how to clear _cookies_.

Comment: Found cache also from within the same details tab.

Comment: Just to add to the confusion - this worked for me for something that I'm pretty sure is "cache" AND the chrome settings include something called "local storage" so I believe that the term "browser cache" may be too general.  My point is that this answer worked for me.

Comment: This also worked for me. Sometimes it's necessary to clear both the cache and cookies when you're doing web development with user sessions.

Comment: @DanielSerodio This solution appears to work for all local data, not just cookies.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution when you are not able to stop on the domain of interest due to redirects.

Comment: "local data" is a specific thing in web dev, not the same as cache

Comment: For Chrome v65 to clear COOKIES, go to Settings > Advanced > Content settings > Cookies > See all cookies and site data > use "search cookies" field to find website and then delete that cookie

Comment: @DanielSerodio as confusing as the text is, this actually clears 'cookies and site data', so it clears cache too as far as I can tell

Answer (score 12):

1. Press <kbd>control</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> (or
   <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> on OS X) to open
   Dev Tools.
2. Right-click the reload button next to the address bar.
3. Choose: "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".

Comment: This is literally identical to the answer above it.  The only difference is the keyboard shortcut used to invoke the inspector/dev tools.

Comment: Ah, well that's kinda uncool then!

Comment: @JVC my bad. I commented that the answer edited and copied this idea into their new version. But, one of the other answers *is* very similar to this and was earlier. Must of missed that one. I usually just let the voting handle these things. As you can see, mine isn’t getting very many votes, so it’s fine.

Answer (score 10):

To delete all data (cache + cookies) **for all subdomains of a domain**:

1. Go to `chrome://settings/siteData`
2. Type domain name in search box (not the one at the top, the small search box top right)
3. Either:

   1. Click the trash icon button for each result
   2. Click 'Remove All Shown' button

This will delete all site data for those sites, including cookies and cache.

Nice thing about this technique is that you can easily clear site data for all subdomains of a domain.

The other way to access this setting screen is:
Three dots menu > Settings > Advanced (at bottom) > Content Settings (under Privacy and Security) > Cookies (yes, name is misleading) > See all cookies and site data

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I have exactly this issue with a subdomain and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: @JVC do you see that subdomain listed when you search?

Comment: It was and then I removed it but no change.  I tried a bunch of other things without success and walked away for a while, came back later and it was cleared up so... I guess something timed out.

Answer (score 3):

In three steps:

1. <kbd>F12</kbd> (open developer tools)
2. <kbd>F1</kbd> (go to settings)
3. Under **Preferences / Network** uncheck **Disable cache (while DevTools is open)**

Note that you can un-dock the DevTools if you would rather keep them as a separate window while open.

Comment: This one is working well if you need to refresh external assets such as js or css

Answer (score 2):

```
Wrench -> Preferences -> Under the Hood -> 
Use DNS pre-fetching to improve page load performance
```

Disable it - thus dumping the whole application cache - reload the affected page - and then re-enable. If this happens often or doesn't clear the issue, some cache upstream from chrome is the problem and you should probably leave chrome's disabled.

Selective invalidation of an application layer cache (which is done strictly for application speed) since chrome has "no business" taking over for the system is might be an answer to some issue, but it isn't a very good answer.

(Lest you get huffy about my "no business" statement, I use pre-fetching myself as I like the zippiness, proper or not)

Comment: Despite your parenthetical objections and the correctness of your solution, I'm huffy anyway.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Disabling DNS prefetching does not clear Chrome's HTTP cache.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the history entries will work in many cases: (Mac)

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> (Open History)
2. Search for your domain
3. Check all the entries. Unfortunately there's no *check all* button at the moment. You don't have to click the checkboxes though, clicking on the time works too.
4. Click `Remove selected items`

Answer (score 1):

Webpack was caching a previous project for me and I need parts of the caching to work so I couldn't use incognito. The top 3 solutions didn't work for my case. What did work and was quick enough to implement was clicking Resources tab in Developer tools, unfolding Cache Storage, and right-clicking to delete the cached data.

Answer (score 1):

**Just clear cache for one site (but leave cookies, local storage, session storage)** - F12 to open DevTools, then click back to main window, right click on refresh button, "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"

**Clear everything for one site (cache, cookies, local storage, session storage)** - F12 to open DevTools, Application tab, "Storage" item in the left menu, click the "Clear site data" button

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

1. Click on `lock` icon in the address bar
   [image]
2. Select **`Cookies and site data`**

[image]

3. Select **`Manage cookies and site data`**

[image]

4. Click on **`delete`** button

[image]