# Google Chrome - Clear Cache for Specific Website

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

I recently created a free web hosting account on x10Hosting. Let's use www.example.x10host.com as my example domain. Before signing up for the domain, I visited the domain to see if it was available. When I saw that it was, I registered it, and immediately went to go look at it on Google Chrome. I still got the "Domain Available" message, so I tried again in 10 minutes, and still got the still got the message. I tried later in Firefox and got it as well. The next day, I tried it in Internet Explorer, and it worked. I am assuming that I now have an outdated cache of the page stored for both Chrome and Firefox. How can I clear just the cache for that specific page so that it will load normally?

Comment: Same way as in IE "ctrl"+"F5"

Comment: You might want to look into [this](https://superuser.com/a/444881/374397) answer. It solves your actual problem of clearing the cache pertaining to **a specific website** (which is currently opened) and **not the whole browser**.

Answer (score 335, accepted):

@dwurf Ctrl Shift + F5/R is Hard Reload, doesn't empty cache.

There is a simple way to do what OP wants:

1. Open Dev Tools by pressing: <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (or on Mac: <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
2. Now  by just leaving dev tools open, right-click or click and **hold** the reload button next to the address bar. Now a somewhat 'hidden menu' opens.
3. Choose: "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"

Comment: and what about history?

Comment: Is this still valid, is there a video of how to do step 2. trying it with no avail

Comment: This doesn't help if site A redirects me to site B, and I want to clear the cache fo site A.

Comment: This is a separate issue. I have encountered this problem too wanting to set a cookie to site A. Old Opera had an option to disable automatic redirections, chrome devs haven't showed interest in this...

Comment: Dev tool > `Network` > Check `Disable cache`

Comment: That's so funny -- I always wondered why that 'hidden menu' sometimes didn't show up; now I realize I probably happened to have Dev Tools open when it did work...

Comment: This was cool to learn about but didn't help me clear the cache of the favicon. Eventually I found http://stackoverflow.com/a/7116701/470749, which worked.

Comment: It is critical to know that **it clears the entire cache of the browser** and not just pertaining to the website currently opened in the current tab.

Comment: Made an account for superuser.com just so I could upvote this. Thanks **alot**!! But I noticed that this does not work on a macbook? What's that about?

Comment: @RBT where did you get that from? I don't think it clears cache from the whole browser...

Comment: looking for a hotkey for this but thanks @ChemicalProgrammer that was really usefull!

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> reloads the page without using the local cache.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> also works, but not in IE

[Chrome Reference](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts)

[Firefox Reference](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly)

[Internet Explorer reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306832)

Comment: @Ramhound Ctrl F5 opens the file browsing window for me.

Comment: Cmd+Shift+R on Mac OS X

Answer (score 9):

In the Chrome DevTools *settings/preferences* there is an option under "Network":

> Disable cache (while DevTools is open)

You can open that, and reload the webpage without the cache.

I had a frustrating situation where a HTTP redirect was cached, so I couldn't just refresh. Opening the DevTools with the "Disable cache..." option open and re-entering the URL was the only thing I could figure out other than doing into the regular Chrome preferences and deleting the cache there (significantly more difficult)

For the record, having the DevTools open also enables a 3rd option on the refresh button (right-click) context menu:

- Normal Refresh
- Hard Refresh
- **Empty Cache and Hard Reload** (careful, this clears your *whole* cache)

There is a good explanation of what these options mean here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969509/363701

Its worth noting that clearing the cache does *not* clear the History.

Comment: No need to open _settings_ (gear icon); there is a "Disable cache" checkbox in the Network menu. ...which I don't quite understand the name of:  because if you reenable the cache, cached behavior does not reappear -- as if the cache had been cleared.

Answer (score 6):

1. On **Chrome**, open `chrome://settings/siteData`
2. Type `example.x10host.com` on the *Search cookies* input.
3. Click on the trash bin to delete cached data and cookies for that web site.

Comment: Only this solution works for me on MAC. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

### [Quick Answer]

Dev tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) or in some cases using <kbd>F12</kbd> | Network | Check <kbd>Disable cache</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when developing I made a redirect page, then I couldn't do `ctrl+f5` on the page because there was not enough time in the page until the redirection method got executed.

Then, I went to console `f12` and then pressing `f1` to see the options, disabled the javascript to avoid redirection, and after that I did a `ctrl+f5` before enabling the javascript again.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

right-click on reload and click on Empty Cache and Hard Reload

[click to see the steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npUbv.png)

Comment: The author is using Windows, your screenshot indicates you are using macOS, is your answer applicable to the author's question?

Comment: Thanks for your help!! but the second step of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/722548/606387) is also saying this

Comment: I am not asking about another user's answer.  I am asking about your answer?  Is your answer applicable to this question?  If there is a second step, is there a reason, you don't include it in the body of your answer?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. I thought steps are obvious from the image, but they are not. I should have mentioned that you need to have your dev tools open before doing right click on the reload button otherwise this menu will not be pop out. Thanks again!!

Comment: The information in your comment should be in your answer.