# Uninstalled Apache, but still see test page

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, php, localhost, xampp

I recently installed Apache HTTP Server from [Apache Haus](https://www.apachehaus.com/) and PHP, and have decided I'd like to experiment with a few other options, so I uninstalled and deleted them. However, when I visit localhost in Chrome (my default browser), I still see the Apache Haus test page used to demonstrate that Apache is working.

I've uninstalled Apache from the Windows 8.1 command prompt, confirmed that it's not in Add or Remove Programs, and deleted the Apache and PHP folders in my C: drive, and even made sure to empty my recycle bin, yet I still see the test page. I'm fairly confident that I truly did uninstall it, because if I look for localhost in Internet Explorer (which I've never used it with), I don't see the test page.

If I install another instance of Apache (i.e., with XAMPP or something), will this cause issues? Is it really fully uninstalled, and is there a way I can remove the test page so that my localhost goes back to the default "This webpage is not available" page?

*EDIT: It's been some time now, and the test page has gone away on its own, but the Apache Haus favicon is still there. So, I'd still like to know if it could still cause issues with another instance of Apache, and how to get rid of it.*

Comment: One thing you didn't list is clearing cache from Chrome.

Comment: @Rocky good idea! I'll give that a shot! Also, some time has passed and the test page is no longer there, so maybe that means it is cache-related? The Apache Haus favicon is still there though, so I'd still like to see if I can get rid of that.

Comment: @Rocky Hmmmmm..... I tried an [Empty Cash and Hard Reload](http://superuser.com/a/722548/219048), but the favicon still remains...