# Can I ask Google Chrome to stop caching specific websites?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-cache

I want Google Chrome to stop caching my localhost since I change its files so often. How do I do this?

I see it can be done while opening the dev tools here: [Clear cache for specific domain name in chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/278948/clear-cache-for-specific-domain-name-in-chrome)

However, I'm looking for a solution that does not require the dev tools to remain open.

I am running WEBrick, a rails server, on localhost and would be happy to tell it not to cache files in any browser.

Comment: Are you willing to consider an alternative method: Configuring your web server to tell *all* browsers (not just chrome) not to cache pages on your site? If so, please edit your question to include which web server you are running on your localhost.

Comment: Using [the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> is a simple way to force a cache refresh][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/385384/325251