# If I open a URL in a new Chrome incognito window, will it act as if I cleared browser cache, cookies etc?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, private-browsing

I have good reasons for not clearing my cookies at the moment. Support staff for a problem site want me to clear browser cache and cookies.

If I open a URL in a new Chrome incognito window, will it act as if I cleared browser cache, cookies etc?

If not, is there another way to test this situation?

Comment: Yes;  You should try incognito mode. You could also just backup your Chrome profile, delete the cookies, and then later restore it.  You can also delete the cookies just for the website in question.

Comment: How do you back up and restore your Chrome profile? There is conflicting information online.

Comment: Related: [When using private browsing, can a website view data stored before private browsing was turned on?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/47149/34757)

Comment: My question was downvoted. Seriously? It seems to me that if incognito mode/private browsing is a quick way to provide a clean browser session, it will make life with remote support staff a lot easier. I just don't want to assume it's true.

Comment: Thanks @Scott. From that topic: "Normally cookies are not shared with a normal browser session. When you start a private browsing session, no cookies will be present. If you close your private browsing session all of your cookies will be deleted."

Comment: Related re cache: [Clear cache for specific domain name in chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/278948/clear-cache-for-specific-domain-name-in-chrome), says: a quicker/simpler way: In Chrome Developer Tools (general settings) check Disable cache. Reload page and re-enable caching by un-checking.

Comment: @Dizzley - You go to the physical location of the profile folder.  You copy that folder to another location.  You delete the original profile folder.  You start Chrome which automatically creates a new Chrome user profile folder.  You then do what the "support staff" requested and when it doesn't work you repeat the process and restore the original profile's folder.

Answer (score 1):

Using Incognito mode, You don't leave browsing history and cookies on your computer, but you can still see your existing history, bookmarks, passwords, Autofill data, and other Chrome settings.

so open your URL in a incognito window which is act as if you have already cleared your browser cache, cookies etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just add a user to your chrome install. You would have a fresh chrome to work with and you would not affect your current install. This only takes 20 seconds in the chrome settings under People.